# Webpack 2 - How to stop generating .js files for CSS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

I'm a total newcomer to Webpack (2) so please forgive me for my simple understanding so far.

Following from a few tutorials around the web, I've cobbled together a working `package.json` and `webpack.babel.config.js` file.

Essentially, I am trying to turn SCSS into CSS, Pug into HTML and JS into Babel'd JS.

When I run my `dist` command, it produces the files, but also along with it, are **.js** files for each **.scss** and **.html** etc. Hopefully the image below can illustrate this:

[image]

Ideally what I'm after is simply, `app.css`, `index.html` and `app.js`.

**webpack.babel.config.js**

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

const extractHtml = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].html'
});

const extractPug = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].[contenthash].pug'
});

const extractScss = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
  allChunks: true
});

let config = {
  stats: {
    assets: false,
    colors: true,
    version: false,
    hash: true,
    timings: true,
    chunks: false,
    chunkModules: false
  },
  entry: {
    'dist/html/app': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pug/app.pug')
    ],
    'dist/js/app': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js')
    ],
    'dist/css/app': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/app.scss')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: extractHtml.extract({
          use: ['html-loader','pug-html-loader?pretty=false&exports=false']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractScss.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: false,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    open: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Portfolio',
      // minify: {
      //   collapseWhitespace: true
      // },
      hash: true,
      template: './dist/html/app.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: false,
      debug: true,
      options: {
        babelLoader: {
          presets: [
            ['es2015']
          ]
        },
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'Explorer >= 9', 'Android >= 4']
          })
        ],
        sassLoader: {
          includePaths: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/sanitize.css/')
          ]
        }
      }
    }),
    extractScss,
    extractHtml,
    extractPug
  ]
}

export default config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Portfolio of Michael Pumo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "prod": "webpack -p",
    "dist": "webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js"
  },
  "author": "Michael Pumo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "html-webpack-pug-plugin": "^0.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta11",
    "pug-html-loader": "1.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.14.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I have many other issues I'd like to resolve too but I'm taking it one issue at a time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use multiple entries, but instead add it to a single entry. For it to work nicely with the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` you should also change the `output` a little. It makes it much easier when you set `output.path` to the `dist/` directory, which also makes more sense conceptually. You'll have one entry point for `app` and then you set the output for the different file types to the corresponding directories. For JavaScript that's the `output.filename` option, which you want in `js/`. Your entry and output should look likes this:

```
entry: {
  app: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pug/app.pug'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/app.scss')
  ]
},
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'js/[name].js'
},
```

And you do the same thing as with `output.filename` for the filename in the extract text plugins:

```
const extractHtml = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'html/[name].html'
});

const extractScss = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',
  allChunks: true
});
```

You didn't use `extractPug` at all, so I left it off and you probably want to remove it.

The output will look likes this:

```
dist
├─ css
│  └─ app.50352154102b272d39e16c28ef00c1ac.css
├─ html
│  └─ app.html
├─ js
│  └─ app.js
└─ index.html
```

Now you also have `index.html` in the `dist` directory and you can simply deploy the `dist` directory, as it's self-contained.

On a side note: You should not use `./dist/html/app.html` as a template to  `html-webpack-plugin` but instead use the `.pug` file directly with the `pug-loader`, which means that you don't even need to add it to the entry or extract the HTML.

Comment: Thank you. I've now done what you suggested. The files are generated, but there's an error saying: "ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin". Opening my HTML file in the /app folder, I see it full of errors too. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The `extract-text-webpack-plugin` error means that you did not put it into `plugins`, make sure you have all of them in there, which you had in the config you posted, but maybe you removed one that you're still using.

Comment: I think it's due to the 'new HtmlWebpackPlugin' in the plugins array. If I comment that part, the build doesn't error. But I need that part to insert the script and link tags, right? The compiled app.html does not contain these parts. I'm still importing the same modules.

Comment: If you use a `.pug` file as the template for the `html-webpack-plugin`, you can't use the extract plugin for `/\.pug$/`. So you would need to remove that and use `pug-loader` instead for that rule. And then you can also remove the `app.pug` from your entry.

Comment: Yes that was it. I should have read what you said earlier: "...but instead use the .pug file directly with the pug-loader, which means that you don't even need to add it to the entry or extract the HTML". It works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not a solution that would allow multiple entries for css, to generate different css bundles based on the entry name? How can we do that? Right now, I get 3 files for each css entry: 1. styles.bundle.js, 2. styles.bundle.css (based on the filename in the output object) and 3. styles.min.css (based on the filename in ExtractTextPlugin options). #1 - I have to delete. #2 and #3 - are identical (I delete #2 and keep #3)
But this is cr*p... I can't believe Webpack exists for quite some years, and still it doesn't provide an easy solution for this so common need.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there is one output for each of your entry points ([this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html#configuration) seems to suggest that way). I believe the most common use case is that there is only one entry point (usually app.js or index.js), and all the required files (like css and other js files) are "`require`d" in the app.js (or import if you are using ES6). That way, there is just one output js file. Also, you can define where to store the individual output files for each loader in the loader's query.

For example, this is a part of my webpack config file:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader']},
      {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader', query: {name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'}},
      {test: /\.(jpg|png)$/, loader: 'file-loader', query: {name: 'img/[name].[ext]'}},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'}
    ]
  }
```

The `query` parameter on each loader is specifying the output directory and filename for each of the loaders.